# what is the point of using the setvbuf() function in c?

Tags: c

Why would you want to set aside a block of memory in `setvbuf()`?

I have no clue why you would want to send your read/write stream to a buffer.

Answer (score 7):

`setvbuf` is not intended to redirect the output to a buffer (if you want to perform IO on a buffer you use `sprintf` & co.), but to tightly control the buffering behavior of the given stream.

In facts, C IO functions don't immediately pass the data to be written to the operating system, but keep an intermediate buffer to avoid continuously performing (potentially expensive) system calls, waiting for the buffer to fill before actually performing the write.

The most basic case is to disable buffering altogether (useful e.g. if writing to a log file, where you want the data to go to disk immediately after each output operation) or, on the other hand, to enable block buffering on streams where it is disabled by default (or is set to line-buffering). This may be useful to enhance output performance.

Setting a specific buffer for output can be useful if you are working with a device that is known to work well with a specific buffer size; on the other side, you may want to have a small buffer to cut down on memory usage in memory-constrained environments, or to avoid losing much data in case of power loss without disabling buffering completely.

Answer (score 1):

In C files opened with e.g. `fopen` are by default buffered. You can use `setvbuf` to supply your own buffer, or make the file operations completely unbuffered (like to `stderr` is).

It can be used to create [`fmemopen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fmemopen) functionality on systems that doesn't have that function.

Answer (score 1):

The size of a files buffer can affect Standard library call I/O rates.  There is a table in Chap 5  of Steven's 'Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment'  that shows I/O throughput increasing dramatically with I/O buffer size, up to ~16K then leveling off.  A lot of other factor can influenc overall I/O throughtput, so this one "tuning" affect may or may not be a cureall.  This is the main reason for "why" other than turning off/on buffering.

Answer (score 0):

Each `FILE` structure has a buffer associated with it internally. The reason behind this is to reduce I/O, and real I/O operations are time costly.
All your read/write will be buffered until the buffer is full. All the data buffered will be output/input in one real I/O operation.

Answer (score 0):

> Why would you want to set aside a block of memory in setvbuf()?

For buffering.

> I have no clue why you would want to send your read/write stream to a buffer.

Neither do I, but as that's not what it does the point is moot.

["The setvbuf() function may be used on any open stream to *change* its buffer"](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf) [my emphasis]. In other words it alread has a buffer, and all the function does is change that. It doesn't say anything about 'sending your read/write streams to a buffer". I suggest you read the *man* page to see what it *actually* says. Especially this part:

> When an output stream is unbuffered, information appears on the destination file or terminal as soon as written; when it is block buffered many characters are saved up and written as a block; when it is line buffered characters are saved up until a newline is output or input is read from any stream attached to a terminal device (typically stdin).